# Reselect (react select) mysteriously doesn't give specified fields

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reselect

I have a react site, and on a specific page, I'm selecting some data by:

```
export const selectAllPhotos = (state) => {
    console.log("State = ", state.photos.photos)
    return state.photos.photos
}
```

and in the console, i'm printing out "state.photos.photos".

In another selector, I'm using the previous defined one as:

```
export const selectIdeabookPhotos =  createSelector(
    selectAllPhotos,
    selectIdeabookPhotoIds,
    (allPhotos, photoIds) =>{
        console.log("LOG => allPhotos", _.keys(allPhotos), allPhotos)
        if(!photoIds) return null
        return photoIds.map(photoId => allPhotos[photoId]).filter(x => x!=undefined)
        //const photos = photoIds && photoIds.map(photoId => state.photos.photos[photoId]).filter(x => x!=undefined)
    }
)
```

However, the strange thing is, it never gets populated if I use this selector in my mapStateToProps:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
    const ideabookId = ownProps.params.ideabookId
    const {ideabooks, ideabookPhotos} = state.ideabooks
    const ideabook = ideabooks[ideabookId]
    const photos = selectIdeabookPhotos(state, ideabookId)
    //const photoIds = ideabookPhotos[ideabookId]
    //const photos = photoIds && photoIds.map(photoId => state.photos.photos[photoId]).filter(x => x!=undefined)

    console.log("all photos => ", photos)

    const {loggedInUser} = state.users
    return {
        ideabook,
        photos: photos,
        loggedInUser
    }
}
```

Mysteriously, if I remove the two comments:

    `//const photoIds = ideabookPhotos[ideabookId]
    //const photos = photoIds && photoIds.map(photoId => state.photos.photos[photoId]).filter(x => x!=undefined)`

and replace the photos not from the selector, but directly by reading it in mapStateToProps, it works fine.

Am I missing something? they seem to be exactly the same

Comment: what does `selectIdeabookPhotoIds` look like ?